# Why it does not produce a Klein bottle?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I cannot understand why the action $\mu : (\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z})\times \mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2  $ given by $\mu((m,n), (x, y)) = (x+ m, (-1)^m(y + n))$ does not produce the Klein bottle $K$. If $X = \mathbb{R}^2 / (\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z})$, then $X \cong K$ would imply that $\pi_1(K,p) \cong \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$, however $\pi_1(K,p) \cong \mathbb{Z} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}$. What's is wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that this action is not an action of $\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z$. Note that it doesn't behave well with respect to the group law on $\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z$:
\begin{align*}
(m_1+m_2,n_1+n_2)\cdot (x,y) &=(x+m_1+m_2, (-1)^{m_1+m_2}(y+n_1+n_2)), \text{ but}\\
(m_2,n_2)\cdot[(m_1,n_1)\cdot (x,y)]&=(m_2,n_2)\cdot(x+m_1, (-1)^{m_1}(y+n_1))\\
&=(x+m_1+m_2, (-1)^{m_2}((-1)^{m_1}(y+n_1)+n_2)\\
&= (x+m_1+m_2, (-1)^{m_1+m_2}(y+n_1)+(-1)^{m_2}n_2)
\end{align*}
So the two sides do not agree and this is not an action.

Another problem is that $\pi_1(K)\neq \mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z_2$! Indeed the fundamental group of the Klein bottle is not Abelian:
$$\pi_1(K)=\langle a,b\,|\,abab^{-1}=1\rangle.$$
You can make your action well-defined by using this group instead, and everything works out the way it should.

Comment: So how is the action that produce a Klein bottle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (because $\mathbb{R}^2$ is its universal covering)?

Comment: @user40276: The group $\langle a,b\,|\, abab^{-1}=1\rangle$ acts on $\mathbb R^2$ by $a\cdot (x,y)=(x+1,y)$ and $b\cdot (x,y)=(x,-y)$. Notice that this satisfied $abab^{-1}(x,y)=(x,y)$ so is well-defined.

Comment: Furthermore if one consider the action $n(x, y) = (x + n, (-1)^n y)$, then it produces a Möbius strip, so I thought something analogous would produce a Klein bottle.

Comment: @user40276: I made a slight mistake in my previous formulas. The corrected formulas should be $a\cdot (x,y)=(x,1-y)$ and $b\cdot (x,y)=(x+1,y)$. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

One possible action of the fundamental group of the Klein bottle as a group of covering transformations on the plane is by the rule

(n,m).(x,y) = (x+n,m+y)  g.(x,y) = (x + 1/2, -y)

Note that the lattice (n,m) is a normal subgroup and that the square of g is in the lattice. This means that the fundamental group of the Klein bottle is an extension of Z2 by ZxZ

0 -> ZxZ -> K -> Z2 -> 0

Conjugation by g is (n,m) -> (n,-m) as is easily verified.

So K is not abelian. Furthermore K is torsion free.

One can also rewrite this group as a split extension of Z by Z

0 -> Z -> K -> Z -> 0

This is because the group element g generates a copy of Z inside K.

The action in one of the comments mentioned above

a⋅(x,y)=(x,1−y) and b⋅(x,y)=(x+1,y)

is not a group of covering transformation because the action of a on the plane has fixed points. In fact the line (x,1/2) is fixed.

One can change the action to a⋅(x,y)=(x+1,−y) and b⋅(x,y)=(x,y+1)